# How to add service time in time window solution?

Tags: c#, optimization, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I have different service time for each location. how can i add these service time in time window solution?

I've already go through 
[or-tools/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrptw.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/39f44709bba203f5ff3bc18fab8098739f189a6d/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrptw.py#L138-L171)

but could not figure it out

Comment: What is service time? What's is time window solution?

Comment: please visit https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw

Comment: the same as Laurent Perron's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692546/how-to-add-delivery-service-time-in-google-ortools-vrp, you can increase the transit time matrix with the service time.

Answer (score 1):

You should build your Transit matrix as follow.

```
Transit(A, B) == ServiceCost(A) + TravelCost(A, B)
```